# How retrieve DNS SRV informations in a WindowPhone7 Application?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, dns, srv

I am looking for a way to query dns to get srv informations.

Nothing seems to exist in standard in .NET.

Is there any simple method to perform this action or should I create it myself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create this yourself.

I'm recommend creating a web service which can do this for you and then calling the webservice from your phone app.
This will move some of the complexity off the phone and into a locaiton it's easier for you to update (if needed). You could also cache results on the web server to reduce the number of lookups required.

**Edit:**
If you are unable to do this through a web service you're likely out of luck.
the [full framework has support for this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.aspx) - but Silverlight doesn't. Internally the full framework version uses sockets - which aren't unavailable on the phone.

The only alternative would be to call some other website which can do the resolution for you. But I'd assume that if you can't call a webservice this is out of the question too. In that case you won't be able to do this with the current SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't use a webservice for some reasons. So I'll need to create it myself :) Do you have any idea from where I can start ? Any documentation ?